# Laravel how to make ajax pagination links work like non ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, pagination

How can I update the links with ajax pagination in Laravel 5.1, links such as the next page and previous page? and how can I limit the amount of links being rendered?

Some code

```
{!! $items->render() !!}

$(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '.pagination a', function (e) {
           if (page != 1) {   //Fix for page 1 because it doesn't get a link with ajax
           $('.pagination li:nth-child(2) > span').replaceWith('<a href="?page=1">1</a>');
  $('.pagination li').removeClass("active");
            $('.pagination li').removeClass("disabled");
            $('.pagination li:nth-child(' + activePage + ')').addClass('active');
            }

      loadItems(page);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });


 function loadItems(pageNumber) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '?page=' + pageNumber,
            beforeSend: function (request) {
                return request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $("meta[name='csrf-     token']").attr('content'));
            },
            success: function (item) {
    }
    )};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use laravel's pagination? [Laravel Pagination Intro](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination#introduction)

in your controller you can use

```
Model::pagination(number of items to see per page);
```

then in the view use

```
{{$variableName->links()}}
```

Comment: I use render() But I want the links to update async and being able to limit the amount of links being rendered.